# Why can i not upload images to my folder anymore?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This was something I had working a few weeks back but after I made some changes to my view file images are now no longer being saved into my assets/uploads folder. I keep getting back the error - You did not select a file to upload. This is despite having made sure the path is definitely correct. What am i doing wrong here?

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class HomeProfile extends CI_Controller 
{


function HomeProfile()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model("profiles");
$this->load->model("profileimages");
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }



 function upload()
      {
    $config['path'] = './web-project-jb/assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $img = $this->session->userdata('img');
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->profileimages->putProfileImage($username, $this->input->post("profileimage"));
//fail show upload form
    if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
{

    $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $this->load->view('shared/header');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/upload_fail', $error);
    $this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ));
    $this->load->view('shared/footer');

    //redirect('homeprofile/index');

}

else
{
    //successful upload so save to database


    $file_data = $this->upload->data();


    $data['img'] = base_url().'./web-project-jb/assets/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
    // you may want to delete the image from the server after saving it to db
    // check to make sure $data['full_path'] is a valid path
    // get upload_sucess.php from link above
    //$image = chunk_split( base64_encode( file_get_contents( $data['file_name'] ) ) );



    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);


    $viewData['username'] = $username;
    $viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');


}

    }



  function index()
  {

$username = $this->session->userdata('username');

$data['profileimages'] = $this->profileimages->getProfileImage($username);

$viewData['username'] = $username;
$viewData['profileText'] = $this->profiles->getProfileText($username);

$this->load->view('shared/header');
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofiletitle', $viewData);
$this->load->view('shared/nav');
//$this->load->view('homeprofile/upload_form', $data);
$this->load->view('homeprofile/homeprofileview', $data, $viewData, array('error' => ' ' ) );
$this->load->view('shared/footer');
   }

   }
```

Here is my view:

```
<div id="maincontent">
<div id="primary"> 
<?//=$error;?>
 <?//=$img;?> 
 <h3><?="Profile Image"?></h3>
  <img src="<?php echo'$img'?>" width='300' height='300'/>
   <?=form_open_multipart('homeprofile/upload');?>
    <input type="file" name="img" value=""/>
    <?=form_submit('submit', 'upload')?>
    <?=form_close();?> 
    <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error;?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: When I select a file and hit upload - its delivering the error back that it's meant to if I hit the button without selecting a file. I actually had this working at one stage

Comment: Look ive done tried a few examples online and I had to start again as I wanted to get it working as before but no luck - im tearing my hair out as to where Im going wrong.

Comment: What is the exact error you get from `array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors())` ??

Comment: it generates the library upload error You did not select a file to upload - it may be kicking back this error as no file seems to being uploaded into the folder and the image isn't displaying on the screen either. But what bothers me is the file not appearing in the folder after i upload it

Answer (score 1):

The Codeigniter Upload class says "*You did not select a file to upload*" because it's looking for the key `userfile` in the `$_FILES` array.

From the docs: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

> #### `$this->upload->do_upload()`
>
> Performs the upload based on the preferences you've set. Note: By
>   default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field
>   called **`userfile`**... If you would like to set your own field name
>   simply pass its value to the do_upload function:
>
> ```
> $field_name = "some_field_name";
> $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
> ```

So you have two choices, change

```
<input type="file" name="img">
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="userfile">
```

... or change

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

to

```
$this->upload->do_upload('img')
```

Comment: Thanks the file is now uploading to the folder, but how come when I upload an image it doesn't appear? I have tried saying <img src="<php=$data?>" width='300' height='300'/> but I get an Undefined variable error msg despite having declared $data in my controller.

Comment: I've [answered your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533249/profile-image-will-upload-to-folder-but-not-to-screen/13534138#13534138), hopefully it helps. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help you with *this* question or if you are satisfied and the uploads are working, and you understand the problem now.

Comment: Hi Welsley - I just saw this comment now - the image paths are now saving correctly to my profileimages database and the image uploads to the screen in my view at first, but when I refresh the image disappears. Im thinking is it something to do with my getProfileImage function - u may see a later question where Ive mentioned this since - but as Im saying this im still having this issue - if u can contribute anything I would be most gratelful